# How to combine 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql

We have 2 SQL queries we use to look up a database lock from a user login, as sometimes we need to unlock it manually.  In short, we run the following query, which will return a few results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT request_session_id
FROM [view_name]
WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]
```

We then take the results one at a time, and run the following query (after updating the @request_session_id variable) until we find the line that shows the correct username in the hostname column of the results (the spid values will correspond to the request_session_id's):

```
DECLARE @request_session_id int;
SET @request_session_id = 107;

SELECT spid, status, hostname
FROM [view_name]
WHERE spid = @request_session_id
```

What I would like to accomplish (if possible), is to combine these 2 queries so it will find the request_session_id's, and then automatically runs the second query, showing a results line for each ID found by the first query.  I'm pretty new to SQL, but I'm familiar with Powershell, so in powershell I would simply save the results from query 1 to a variable, and then use foreach to cycle those results through query 2.  I'm just not sure how I would get to the same end result with SQL.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Andrew

Comment: Do both queries really adress the same table/view? Both are `FROM [view_name]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want `IN`?

```
SELECT spid, status, hostname
FROM [view_name]
WHERE spid IN (SELECT request_session_id
               FROM [view_name]
               WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would us `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery. Unlike when using `IN`, this properly handles the case when the first query returns a `request_session_id` that is null:

```
SELECT spid, status, hostname
FROM [view_name] v1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [view_name] v2
    WHERE 
        [condition1] 
        AND [condition2]
        AND v1.spid = v2.request_session_id
)
```

Note: likely, both `[view_name]`s belong to different tables; otherwise, the logic would be largely simplified.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't specify.  The view names are different, and the view_name in the second query might even be a table vs a view, I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon said above:

```
SELECT spid, status, hostname
FROM [view_namea]
WHERE spid IN (SELECT request_session_id
               FROM [view_nameb]
               WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `IN` clause to filter the `spid` values that you want:

```sql
SELECT spid, status, hostname
FROM [view_name]
WHERE spid IN (
  SELECT request_session_id
  FROM [view_name]
  WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]
);
```

This will return results for `spids` that match the conditions in the `IN` sub-query.  You don't need to include the `DISTINCT` there, since that just adds extra processing.